# Getting relative source/destination in Gulp task

Tags: javascript, gulp

Let's say I have a file at `/Users/me/app/src/scripts/foo.js`. I set up a gulp tasks that writes this file to `/Users/me/app/dist/scripts/foo.js`:

```
gulp.src('src/scripts/foo.js', base: 'src')
.pipe(...)
.pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
```

I'm writing a simple plugin and need to know `scripts/foo.js`. I was expecting `file.relative` to be this partial path, but instead it provides `foo.js`. I don't see a way to get `scripts/foo.js` from any combination of `file.path`, `file.cwd`, `file.base`, etc.

How can I get the part of the path I need?

Comment: I'm sorry but relative to what? relative to base?

Comment: Don't mind me. Finally understand your question. I'm posting an answer.

Comment: Please let me know if I can rephrase any part of the question to be more clear for anyone who comes across this in the future.

Comment: Please check out my answer to see if I understand you correctly

Answer (score 12):

Assuming that you want the path relative to your specified base, you would want to use something like node's path module to do the extraction:

```
var path = require('path');
// this is how you get the relative path from a vinyl file instance
path.relative(path.join(file.cwd, file.base), file.path);
```

Here is an example gulpfile using your example:

```
var path = require('path'),
    gulp = require('gulp'),
    through = require('through2');

function parsePath() {
    return through.obj(function (file, enc, cb) {
        console.log(file.base);
        console.log(file.cwd);
        console.log(file.path);
        console.log(path.relative(path.join(file.cwd, file.base), file.path))
        cb();
    });
}

gulp.task('default', function () {
    gulp.src('src/scripts/foo.js', { base: 'src'})
        .pipe(parsePath())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Here is the output when I run this gulpfile:

```
src
/Volumes/Data/Project/sandbox/gulp-ex
/Volumes/Data/Project/sandbox/gulp-ex/src/scripts/foo.js
scripts/foo.js
```

Here is the project folder structure

```
gulp-ex/
    |_ gulpfile.js
    |_ src/scripts/foo.js
    |_ dist
```

Comment: This is close, but on my system it outputs `../../../src/scripts/foo.js`, when we want `scripts/foo.js`.

Comment: Interesting. Could you `console.log` file.cwd, file.base, file.path in parsePath and post the output?

Comment: cwd: /app, base: /app/src/scripts, path: /app/src/scripts/foo.js

Comment: I don't think this is correct anymore. Whenever I `console.log` the `file.base` it is always an absolute path, too.

Comment: @trysis which gulp/node version are you using? Do you also mind pasting your whole gulpfile here?

Comment: `path.relative(file.cwd, file.path)` worked for me (doesn't include `../../..` in the output)