# Gulp rename and base path

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-rename

I am searching for a solution allowing to modify the base part of path.
I have a path like 'app/assets/theme/file.css' that i get with 'app/**/*.css' pattern and I would like to transform it to 'dist/assets/theme/file.css'.

For now I am doing something like:

```
gulp.src(paths.styles)
    .pipe(rename(function(path) {
        path.dirname = paths.dist + path.dirname;
    })
```

wich give me 'app/dist/assets/theme/file.css' instead of 'dist/assets/theme/file.css'. I don't find the way to erase 'app/' part.

How could I obtain the good result (using rename or another plugin if necessary) ?

Answer (score 3):

There is a `base` option in `gulp.src` which you can use

```
gulp.src(paths.styles, {base: 'app'})
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
```

Read the [doc](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I already read the doc but what I want to do is not moving the file but retrieving the path.

Comment: @ChrisV then you may be interested in this answer I wrote some time ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29614917/getting-relative-source-destination-in-gulp-task/29615354#29615354

Answer (score 0):

You could try a String replace(), something like this:

`gulp.src(paths.styles)
    .pipe(rename(function(path) {
      var newPath = paths.dist + path.dirname;
      path.dirname = newPath.replace('app/');
    })`

Comment: Thank you for your answer Matt but I was actually searching for something more general that could handle a "glob string" because my example is just a simplification of what I want to do.